# Change label text while image in UIScrollview changes

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to create an image gallery similar to this:

http://sweettutos.com/2015/04/13/how-to-make-a-horizontal-paging-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-storyboards-swift/

Where each time the user swipes and the image changes and the label title changes.I have written the code and included the `if` statement, however, it does not work properly and it only changes as one value.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var mainscrollview: UIScrollView!
var imageArray = [UIImage]()


    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mainscrollview.frame = view.frame
        imageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "goku"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "boruto"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tail"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "sage"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "tobi")]

        for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
        let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = imageArray[i]
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)

            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.mainscrollview.frame.width,height: self.mainscrollview.frame.height)
            mainscrollview.contentSize.width = mainscrollview.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
            mainscrollview.addSubview(imageView)

            let gokuImage = UIImage(named: "goku")
            let borutoImage = UIImage(named: "boruto")

            if imageView.image == gokuImage{

                label.text = "Goku"
            }
            if imageView.image == borutoImage{

                label.text = "bor"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is where the project is going wrong:

```
let gokuImage = UIImage(named: "Goku")
            let borutoImage = UIImage(named: "boruto")

            if imageView.image == gokuImage{

                label.text = "Goku"
            }
            if imageView.image == borutoImage{

                label.text = "bor"
            }
```

***I think this is because the if statement can not directly access the current image that is being displayed in the UIScroll view.***

Here is the link to my project: http://www.mediafire.com/file/adkzcpvdtodlyl5/gallery_copy.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want to do, here is one of the option available which is fairly simple:

1. Your label is in your ScrollView, so it will scroll with your first image. You need to move it above your ScrollView, at the same hierarchy level as the ScrollView.
2. In order to change your label's text when you scroll, you can detect when your page has stopped decelerating. To do so:

   (a) Add `UIScrollViewDelegate` to `class ViewController: UIViewController`,

   (b) in viewDidLoad(), add 'mainscrollview.delegate = self',

   (c) write the 'scrollViewDidEndDecelerating' method.

In the end, your code should look like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var mainscrollview: UIScrollView!

  @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

  var imageArray = [UIImage]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     imageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "goku"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "boruto"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tail"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "sage"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "tobi")]
     mainscrollview.frame = view.frame
     mainscrollview.delegate = self
     label.text = "Initial label value is Boruto"

     for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
         let imageView = UIImageView()
         imageView.image = imageArray[i]
         imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
         let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
         imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.mainscrollview.frame.width,height: self.mainscrollview.frame.height)
         mainscrollview.contentSize.width = mainscrollview.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
         mainscrollview.addSubview(imageView)
        }
  }

  func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
    // Test the offset and calculate the current page after scrolling ends
    let pageWidth:CGFloat = mainscrollview.frame.width
    let currentPage:CGFloat = floor((mainscrollview.contentOffset.x-pageWidth/2)/pageWidth)+1

    // Change the text accordingly
    if Int(currentPage) == 0{
      label.text = "Boruto"
    }else if Int(currentPage) == 1{
      label.text = "Goku"
    }else if Int(currentPage) == 2{
      label.text = "Sage"
    }else if Int(currentPage) == 3{
      label.text = "Tail"
    }else if Int(currentPage) == 4{
      label.text = "Tobi"
    }else{
      label.text = "Other character"
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the UILabel from storyboards and UIImageView from the code. You add all the images to the scrollView, so that everyone follows one another, but you use your label only with the first image.

In other words, you need to add UILabel to the code and add it to each image. Instead of a lot of "if-cycle", I suggest you use an array of labels, just as you use the image.

```
   var labelArray = [String]() 

   // in viewDidLoad add your label names
   labelArray = ["goku", "boruto", "next word", "next word", "next word"] 

   // create UILabel
   let yourLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: xPosition, y: self.mainscrollview.frame.height - 100, width: self.mainscrollview.frame.width, height: 40))

   // add each labelName to each image                
   yourLabel.text = labelArray[i]

   // add image and label to scrollView
   mainscrollview.addSubview(imageView)
   mainscrollview.addSubview(yourLabel)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is remove the label from the scroll view and add it into the main view i.e the scrollview and the label should have sibling relationship rather than parent-child relationship.

Modify your ViewController accordingly

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
// your other code

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mainscrollview.delegate = self

    // your other code
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let imageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    switch imageNumber {
    case 0:
        label.text = "Goku"
    case 1:
        label.text = "Bor"
    case 2:
        label.text = "Tail"
    case 3:
        label.text = "Sage"
    case 4:
        label.text = "Tobi"
    default:
        label.text = "Unknown"
    }
  }

}
```